# Generics example does not work? Alternatives or suggestions?

Tags: java, generics

I am getting this error with the following code:

> `The method getItemProperty(capture#2-of ? extends GenericTest.Item) in the type GenericTest.BaseContainer<capture#2-of ? extends GenericTest.Item> is not applicable for the arguments (GenericTest.Item)`

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class GenericTest {

public class Item {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class WordItem extends Item {

}

public abstract class BaseContainer<T extends Item> {
    public String getItemProperty(T item) {
        return item.getValue();
    }
}

public class Document extends BaseContainer<WordItem> {
}

public static class ContainerFactory {
  public static BaseContainer<? extends Item> getContainer(Item item) {
     return new GenericTest().new Document();
  }
}

@Test
public void theTest(){
    Item item = new WordItem();
    BaseContainer<? extends Item> container = ContainerFactory.getContainer(item);
    String str = container.getItemProperty(item); //this line does not compile
}
}
```

I´m using Eclipse Helios with jdk 1.6.0_16.

Comment: What is the error the compiler gives you?

Comment: please add more information to this question.  Or it is in danger of getting closed.

Comment: this is the compiler error
The method getItemProperty(capture#2-of ? extends GenericTest.Item) in the type GenericTest.BaseContainer<capture#2-of ? extends GenericTest.Item> is not applicable for the arguments (GenericTest.Item)

I´m using Eclipse Helios with jdk 1.6.0_16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error, change your code to:

```
public static class ContainerFactory {
  public static <T extends Item>BaseContainer<T> getContainer(Item item) {
     return (BaseContainer<T>) new GenericTest().new Document();
  }
}

@Test
public void theTest(){
    Item item = new WordItem();
    BaseContainer<Item> container = ContainerFactory.getContainer(item);
    String str = container.getItemProperty(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `container` is a `BaseContainer<? extends Item>`, i.e. it is a container of *some* subtype of `Item`. However, the compiler has no way of ensuring that the subtype in question is actually `Item` itself. And in fact it is `WordItem`, not `Item`. The overall problem is that your generic parameter usage is not consistent and full.

I could make your code compile with these modifications:

```
public class Document<T extends Item> extends BaseContainer<T> {
}

public static class ContainerFactory {
  public static <T extends Item> BaseContainer<T> getContainer(T item) {
     return new Test().new Document<T>();
  }
}

@Test
public void theTest(){
    WordItem item = new WordItem();
    BaseContainer<WordItem> container = ContainerFactory.getContainer(item);
    String str = container.getItemProperty(item);
}
```

This differs from TrueSoft's suggestion in that here `Document` is also made generic - this may not be what you want (you gave no info regarding this), but at least this way there is no unsafe cast required within `getContainer()`.